# How to solve Path , file name too long while trying to publish in visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2008, console-application, publish

I am using Visual studio 2008,

I have created a C# console application as client for WCF web service, When I try to publish the client am getting the following error.

`Error  105 Unable to copy file "bin\x64\Release\GameBoardWebServerServiceClient.exe.manifest" to "bin\x64\Release\app.publish\Application Files\GameBoardWebServerServiceClient_1_0_0_4\GameBoardWebServerServiceClient.exe.manifest". The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets    3554`

The problem is occuring here in Microsoft.Common.targets file

```
<!-- Copy files to publish folder -->
    <Copy
        SourceFiles=
            "@(_ApplicationManifestFinal);
            @(_DeploymentResolvedManifestEntryPoint);
            @(_DeploymentManifestFiles);
            @(ReferenceComWrappersToCopyLocal);
            @(ResolvedIsolatedComModules);
            @(_DeploymentLooseManifestFile)"
        DestinationFiles=
            "@(_ApplicationManifestFinal->'$(_DeploymentApplicationDir)%(TargetPath)');
            @(_DeploymentManifestEntryPoint->'$(_DeploymentApplicationDir)%(TargetPath)$(_DeploymentFileMappingExtension)');
            @(_DeploymentManifestFiles->'$(_DeploymentApplicationDir)%(TargetPath)$(_DeploymentFileMappingExtension)');
            @(ReferenceComWrappersToCopyLocal->'$(_DeploymentApplicationDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)$(_DeploymentFileMappingExtension)');
            @(ResolvedIsolatedComModules->'$(_DeploymentApplicationDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)$(_DeploymentFileMappingExtension)');
            @(_DeploymentLooseManifestFile->'$(_DeploymentApplicationDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)$(_DeploymentFileMappingExtension)')"
        SkipUnchangedFiles="true"
        OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="$(OverwriteReadOnlyFiles)"/>

    <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(_DeploymentManifestDependencies)"
        DestinationFiles="@(_DeploymentManifestDependencies->'$(_DeploymentApplicationDir)%(TargetPath)$(_DeploymentFileMappingExtension)')"
        SkipUnchangedFiles="true"
        OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="$(OverwriteReadOnlyFiles)"
        Condition="'%(_DeploymentManifestDependencies.DependencyType)'=='Install'"/>

    <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(_ReferenceScatterPaths)"
        DestinationFiles="@(_ReferenceScatterPaths->'$(_DeploymentApplicationDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)$(_DeploymentFileMappingExtension)')"
        SkipUnchangedFiles="true"
        OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="$(OverwriteReadOnlyFiles)"/>`
```

How to solve this ?

Is there any way to change the maximum size parameter or any such work around without having to reduce the filename

Comment: It would be helpful for us to solve if you can provide some code here.

Comment: @jadavparesh06 Its not related to my code as I am able to build and run the application. Also the executable from bin folder. Its just that am getting errors while publish inside the copy part.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is nothing to do with code.

Comment: Your issue it seems stems from a temp directory visual studio writes to, I'm afraid I don't think that temp directory can be changed.

Comment: @PaulZahra That is for a problem in code not for the problem while copying files in publish.

Comment: Did you read the error? What is the root path before the `bin` folder? Is there any way you can shorten that path?